# ServiceStack Angular4 Selfhosted

Tags: angular, servicestack, self-hosting

Is there an easy way to create a project like the ServiceStack Angular4 from the VS Template but for a Self Hosted Service?  Would be really nice to have the instructions on what to change and what to include/copy etc...

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between an ASP.NET project and a self-hosting project is that ASP.NET Web Apps inherit from `AppHostBase` whilst Self-Hosting Apps inherit from `AppSelfHostBase`.

The other difference you need to account for are [serving static assets](http://docs.servicestack.net/self-hosting#serving-razor-views-or-static-files-from-httplistener) where ASP.NET Apps will serve static assets from the project root but self-hosting Apps only serve static assets in the `/bin` directory where it's run from. This means you need to either need to set the **Copy Output Directory** of all static assets you want available to **Copy if newer**.

Alternatively you can change the Web Host Physical path to point to your project's directory, e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
#if DEBUG
    DebugMode = true,
    WebHostPhysicalPath = "~/../..".MapServerPath(),
#endif
});
```